# Recommendation for Domain Driven Design modelling

Tags: domain-driven-design, abp

I'm trying to model two type of invoice in ddd.
Purchase invoice and sales invoice.
Simply behaviour is purchase invoice increases stock quantities and sales invoice decreases.
Which one is rigt for ddd?
1- Defining PurchaseInvoice and SalesInvoice separately that implement business logic in two different aggregate?
2- Defining one Invoice aggregate and implement business logic help with dicriminator field?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like `Purchase` and `Sales` are  two completely different *Bounded Context*. Which means that an `Invoice` *Entity* could exist in both. A discriminator is a smell that you're dealing with two different things. So neither 1 or 2 seems to be the best option. I'd rather go with an `Invoice` in the `Purchase` *Bounded Context* and an `Invoice` in the `Purchase` *Bounded Context*.

Comment: For your last sentence. Invoice is an entity that exist in purchase and sales bounded contexts. Thank you.